# FreeRtos stm32f4 stuck in vTaskDelay

Tags: arm, stm32f4, freertos

hello i'am using FreeRtos API with stm32f4 microcontroller ,  the program gets stuck when it enters vTaskDelay , when I debug it I see that it is stuck in this line (2588 of tasks.c at function vTaskDelay)

```
            if( listCURRENT_LIST_LENGTH( &( pxReadyTasksLists[ tskIDLE_PRIORITY ] ) ) > ( UBaseType_t ) 1 )
        {
            taskYIELD();
        }
```

thank a lot for your help

Comment: There are a lot of things that could cause this, but you're probably misusing the mutitasking API somewhere else.

Comment: Not enough information provided to answer this

Comment: hi @Daniel i discovered that the code never reaches " xTaskIncrementTick " wich means the tick interrupt doesn't execute ,  
how to make it work ?

Answer (score 3):

well I found the reason why this error happened
it's just that time doesn't seem to advance because the systick interruption was like doing nothing , and this because i used a FreeRTOSConfig.h generated with stmcube and the following was commented

```
/* IMPORTANT: This define MUST be commented when used with STM32Cube firmware, 
to prevent overwriting SysTick_Handler defined within STM32Cube HAL */
/* #define xPortSysTickHandler SysTick_Handler*/
```

, I decommented it , i also had to comment the definition of the systick interruption in stm32f4xx__it.c to avoid duplicate definition

Answer (score 0):

With STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.13.1 and FreeRTOS V8.2.3 you need to define the symbol `USE_RTOS_SYSTICK`.

Here is a working example:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_nucleo_144.h"

// don't forget to define USE_RTOS_SYSTICK globally!

#include <cmsis_os.h>

#define LED_PIN     GPIO_PIN_0
#define LED_PORT        GPIOB

void blinky_task( void* pvParameters)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        vTaskDelay( 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LED_PORT, LED_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);

        vTaskDelay( 200  / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin( LED_PORT, LED_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin  = LED_PIN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init( LED_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    xTaskCreate( blinky_task, (char*) "blinky", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, 0, 1, 0);
    vTaskStartScheduler();
}
```